# Instagram Authentication in Safari

Tags: javascript, authentication, safari, instagram

I am using client-side authentication as described in the Instagram API here:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

The site I am using this for is here:

http://www.soulfulcreations.com/product/canvas-print/

The problem I am having is that Instagram is authenticating as expected in Chrome and FF, but in Safari, the access token is never being returned into the URL. The application hangs at authentication because it is waiting for the token to be returned as a hash in the URL, but it never comes through.

Any ideas why it would work in Chrome and FF but not Safari? I should also note that it was working fine up until a couple weeks ago, but it stopped working seemingly spontaneously (which I really hate saying as a coder who relies on logic).

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my site http://slidetagram.com

This is an known issue on Safari.

To fix this you have to add an extra slash before the # on your page to be redirected.

In my case I've changed from
http://slidetagram.com/slide#access_token=...
to
http://slidetagram.com/slide/#access_token=...

After that change, it worked fine!